# How integrate Nodejs and Reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, koa

I have some code on Nodejs (Koa): identification and reg users, work with DB.
After successful identification or registration I wanna to transfer control to code on Reactjs, with some parameters (user info). Then call back control to nodejs. How it can be realized ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a look at the help section for asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Hey @Алекс, unfortunately, it's hard to write an objective answer to this question. 1) You haven't provided any specific details about your challenge, which makes reproducing your situation impossible. 2) The question is overly broad. It's better to read some tutorials online and ask questions about specific things you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

use [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga).

> is a library that aims to make application side effects (i.e. asynchronous things >like data fetching and impure things like accessing the browser cache) easier to >manage, more efficient to execute, easy to test, and better at handling failures.